Why do propellers have a specified range of diameters, with both maximum and minimum limits?
I want to know what exactly the minimum and maximum diameter means in a prop. For example, in a Cessna 152, we have a McCauley prop with a minimum diameter of 67.5 inches and a maximum diameter of 69 inches. For reference, the propeller model number is 1A103/TCM6958.
I'm having some trouble understanding what exactly this range means. Is it related to the expansion of the prop due to heat? For example, it has a diameter of 67.5 inches when cold and expands to 69 inches when hot?

The prop is 69 inches when new.  Longer and it would probably hit the ground or other issues.
As the aircraft is used, it may get nicks in the prop.  These are most likely to happen near the tip.  A certificated mechanic is allowed to blend things like that out.  If one side ends up shortened, they need to do the same to the other side to keep it mass and aerodynamically balanced.
In the end, the 67.5 is a maximum limit on how much the prop can be shortened through its life of maintenance activities.

Usually the aircraft / engine / propeller is certificated as a unit.  The performance numbers in the flight manual etc. are all specific to that combination.
There can be STC's for other props -- or revisions, etc.  Just like for alternate engines.  However, those usually will come with a different flight manual.  Those also probably also have different max / min limits on the prop diameter.
The 69 in 1A103/TCM6958 probably means 69" diameter and the 58 probably means 58" of pitch.

It may seem odd to have a limit on how much can be removed, but there must be some limit.  If a propeller is in service for 30 or 50 years, then a mechanic working on it needs to know 'how much is too much'.

@MichaelHall I agree that the flight manual performance numbers will have some margin in them that are good to the 67.5 diameter -- but that the company doesn't want to promise anything about a prop trimmed to 65".  When you suggested a 68" prop, I thought you were talking about a different part number with a nominal 68" diameter -- a different design, possibly from a different manufacturer.

A different part number needs an STC and potentially revisions to the flight manual.  Take two 69" props - one a 'cruise' prop and the other a 'climb' prop. They'll differ in takeoff distance, rate of climb, cruise speed, and fuel economy at cruise. The airplane manufacturer won't give allowance for "any propeller between 67.5 and 69 inches diameter". Of course, company B might want to offer a bolt-on equivalent to company A's propeller. In that case, their two 69" offerings may have nearly identical performance - but it would still be certificated separately and require an STC proving safety.

got it, thx.  deleting comments ...

A mechanic in the field will not remove material from a tip that shortens the blade beyond some light dressing that his no noticeable effect visually. 99% of dressing is on the blade's leading edge. When I dress out my prop I'll count the file strokes and try to duplicate the action on the other blade.

They may have a tight range on fixed pitch props due to engine loading factors.
The tip of a 69 inch propeller at 2400 rpm will move at:
2400 rpm × $\pi$ × 69 inches × 1 mile/5280 feet × 1 foot/12 inches × 60 minutes/hour = 492 mph
The extra inch and a half on the end will produce considerably more thrust at a given rpm.  The shorter one will need higher rpm for the same performance.
Higher rpm shortens engine life.  For an aircraft on a regular maintenance schedule, deviation from specified engine loading may not be safe.

The 67.5 inches is the shortest a propeller shop can make the blades if they have to remove damage, say from a minor tip strike or a fatigue crack detected during an inspection.
Mechanics in the field will generally only dress out blade leading edges due to nicks and dings. They won't remove material from a tip because specialised processes and tooling is required to have the reworked blades identical and in balance.  If a tip itself gets damaged or bent or has a crack, the prop will go into a certified shop.
The minimum length specification means the shop can remove up to 3/4 inches off each tip to remove the damaged metal and make the prop airworthy again (while doing that, they may repitch it slightly, twist it coarser, to compensate for the lost blade area in order to get the same static RPM when running the engine on the ground). If any more material than that has to be removed, the propeller is ready for its new life as a clock.
